# Search and replace multidimentional array using language file

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

i have a language file that looks like this

```
$lang['dashboard ']='Dashboard';
$lang['financial_dashboard']='Financial Dashboard';
$lang['project_dashboard']='Project Dashboard';
```

Array result from the database

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 109 [text] => dashboard [items] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [text] => financial_dashboard [items] => 109 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 108 [text] => project_dashboard [items] => 109 ) ) )
```

How can i find and replace the values in the array with the values in my language file but maintain the array as it is, so that my final output looks something like this

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 109 [text] => Dashboard [items] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [text] => Financial Dashboard [items] => 109 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 108 [text] => Project Dashboard [items] => 109 ) ) )
```

Any suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply loop through the array and check if the replacement texts are available using [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php). If found, replace it with the corresponding $lang value.

```
$replace = array_keys($lang); // Text to replace i.e dashboard, financial_dashboard, project_dashboard

foreach ($data as &$dt) {
  if (is_array($dt['items'])) {
    foreach ($dt['items'] as &$d) {
        if (in_array($d['text'], $replace)) {
            $d['text'] = $lang[$d['text']];
        }
    }
  } else {
      if (in_array($dt['text'], $replace)) {
        $dt['text'] = $lang[$dt['text']];
      }
  }
}
```